# grep list of names and information from bigger file

Tags: text-processing, grep, awk

I have two files: one with list of names (500 entries) and other having some more information for each entry in A.txt and extra entries too.

File A.txt (each line is starting with `>` (fasta format) and has spaces, digits and special characters too, but in single line)

```
>xyz, B=123 
>abc, B=231
>mnp, B=567
```

File B.txt (has some particular information for each entry in A.txt in next line and has extra  entries than file A)

```
>xyz, B=123
01010101010100101
>abc, B=231
1011110000011100000000
>mnp, B=567
10101
>opq, B=678
101010101010101001
>lmn, B=123
101010100000011
```

Result

```
>xyz, B=123
01010101010100101
>abc, B=231
1011110000011100000000
>mnp, B=567
10101
```

I want to grep the entries in list A.txt from list B.txt

thanks

Comment: If, according to your example, B has exactly 1 extra line for each line from A, you could try a simple `grep -F -f A.txt -A 1 B.txt`.

Comment: @jw013 but this giving a line -- after each group.

Comment: Yes that is an unavoidable side effect of `grep -A`.  You can get rid of it by piping it to `grep -v '^--$'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you want to print just two lines for each match, with GNU or FreeBSD grep, you can pass `A.txt` as a list of patterns to `grep` and tell it to print the line after the match. This produces extra lines with just `--` between each match, you can easily remove them with an extra call to grep.

```
grep -A1 -Ff A.txt B.txt | grep -vx -- '--'
```

If the number of lines per section isn't fixed, you can use awk. First read the file containing the text to look for, then for each line in `B.txt` that starts a new section, either start or stop printing depending on whether the section head is in `A.txt` or not.

```
awk -v patterns_file=A.txt '
  BEGIN {
    while (getline <patterns_file) patterns_array[$0] = 1;
    close(patterns_file);
  }
  /^/ { matching = $0 in patterns_array }
  matching { print }
' B.txt
```

Comment: Nice @giles, but why would grep suffer if the number of lines changes?

Comment: @terdon The grep method only works if all the matching sections have the same number of lines, because that's the number you need to specify on (`-A`).

Comment: @Giles Ah, ok, of course. I thought you meant it would not work if the number of records was variable. Gotcha.